# My pulumi stack was created with an older plugin version that I can't install on M1 mac

Tags: pulumi

I have a Pulumi project which I haven't touched (deployed etc) for a while.

Now I need to make some changes but I get the "403 HTTP error fetching plugin" [described here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/support/troubleshooting/#403-http-error-fetching-plugin)

The description in the docs makes sense: I have bought a new Apple M1 laptop since last time I worked on it, my stack was built with the digitalocean provider v3.1.1 but I can't install that version on my new laptop.

The docs say that if you have access to an Intel system, set up your project there, update the providers and run `pulumi up`.  The implication is that you can install both old and latest versions of the provider plugin, `pulumi up` will update the stack using the latest version. After that I should be able to manage the stack from my new laptop using the latest provider version.

I asked on Pulumi Slack about this and confirmed the above.

But it doesn't seem to work for me.

First I started a Docker container with `--platform=linux/amd64` to emulate Intel.  Inside that I checked out my project, installed pulumi and the old and new provider versions.

In my docker container `pulumi plugin ls` shows:

```
NAME          KIND      VERSION  SIZE   INSTALLED  LAST USED
cloudflare    resource  4.7.0    38 MB  n/a        1 day ago
cloudflare    resource  2.8.0    46 MB  n/a        1 day ago
digitalocean  resource  4.14.0   42 MB  n/a        1 day ago
digitalocean  resource  3.1.1    45 MB  n/a        1 day ago
```

From there I successfully ran `pulumi up`.

However if I go back to my local shell and try `pulumi preview` I get:

> error: could not load plugin for digitalocean provider 'urn:pulumi:staging::myproject::pulumi:providers:digitalocean::default': no resource plugin 'pulumi-resource-digitalocean' found in the workspace at version v3.1.1 or on your $PATH, install the plugin using `pulumi plugin install resource digitalocean v3.1.1`

So despite updating the stack Pulumi is still trying to use the old provider version that I can't install.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to update your pulumi program's dependencies.

Simply installing the new plugin isn't enough.

If you do `pulumi stack export` you'll see a JSON file with all your resources. Those resources have a *provider* attached to them with a specific version of the plugin. As an example:

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "deployment": {
    "manifest": {
      "time": "2022-06-23T12:03:30.071863-07:00",
      "magic": "eccb7d9cc1cab43d7465783c52b0648063d5e7228dd3bb2fc7600583a8bca5d5",
      "version": "v3.34.1"
    },
    "secrets_providers": {
      "type": "service",
      "state": {
        "url": "https://api.pulumi.com",
        "owner": "jaxxstorm",
        "project": "s3_event_bridge",
        "stack": "dev"
      }
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "urn": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::s3_event_bridge-dev",
        "custom": false,
        "type": "pulumi:pulumi:Stack",
        "outputs": {
          "bucketName": "test001-c86ab36"
        },
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "urn": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:providers:aws::default_5_9_1",
        "custom": true,
        "id": "484b75ed-d5cd-4ee1-96d1-b3f641236ab6",
        "type": "pulumi:providers:aws",
        "inputs": {
          "region": "us-west-2",
          "version": "5.9.1"
        },
        "outputs": {
          "region": "us-west-2",
          "version": "5.9.1"
        },
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "urn": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::aws:s3/bucket:Bucket::test001",
        "custom": true,
        "id": "test001-c86ab36",
        "type": "aws:s3/bucket:Bucket",
        "inputs": {
          "__defaults": [
            "bucket",
            "forceDestroy"
          ],
          "acl": "private",
          "bucket": "test001-c86ab36",
          "forceDestroy": false,
          "tags": {
            "Environment": "Dev",
            "Name": "My bucket",
            "__defaults": []
          }
        },
        "outputs": {
          "accelerationStatus": "",
          "acl": "private",
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::test001-c86ab36",
          "bucket": "test001-c86ab36",
          "bucketDomainName": "test001-c86ab36.s3.amazonaws.com",
          "bucketRegionalDomainName": "test001-c86ab36.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
          "corsRules": [],
          "forceDestroy": false,
          "grants": [],
          "hostedZoneId": "Z3BJ6K6RIION7M",
          "id": "test001-c86ab36",
          "lifecycleRules": [],
          "loggings": [],
          "objectLockConfiguration": null,
          "region": "us-west-2",
          "replicationConfiguration": null,
          "requestPayer": "BucketOwner",
          "serverSideEncryptionConfiguration": null,
          "tags": {
            "Environment": "Dev",
            "Name": "My bucket"
          },
          "tagsAll": {
            "Environment": "Dev",
            "Name": "My bucket"
          },
          "versioning": {
            "enabled": false,
            "mfaDelete": false
          },
          "website": null
        },
        "parent": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::s3_event_bridge-dev",
        "provider": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:providers:aws::default_5_9_1::484b75ed-d5cd-4ee1-96d1-b3f641236ab6",
        "propertyDependencies": {
          "acl": null,
          "tags": null
        },
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "urn": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::aws:s3/bucketNotification:BucketNotification::bucketNotification",
        "custom": true,
        "id": "test001-c86ab36",
        "type": "aws:s3/bucketNotification:BucketNotification",
        "inputs": {
          "__defaults": [],
          "bucket": "test001-c86ab36",
          "eventbridge": false
        },
        "outputs": {
          "bucket": "test001-c86ab36",
          "eventbridge": false,
          "id": "test001-c86ab36",
          "lambdaFunctions": [],
          "queues": [],
          "topics": []
        },
        "parent": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::s3_event_bridge-dev",
        "dependencies": [
          "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::aws:s3/bucket:Bucket::test001"
        ],
        "provider": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:providers:aws::default_5_9_1::484b75ed-d5cd-4ee1-96d1-b3f641236ab6",
        "propertyDependencies": {
          "bucket": [
            "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::aws:s3/bucket:Bucket::test001"
          ],
          "eventbridge": null
        },
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you look at my `BucketNotification` resource, you can see a `provider` field which has a version in it for the AWS provider I've used:

```
"provider": "urn:pulumi:dev::s3_event_bridge::pulumi:providers:aws::default_5_9_1::484b75ed-d5cd-4ee1-96d1-b3f641236ab6"
```

Which in this case is `5.9.1`

So, in order to fix this problem, you need to update your resources to have a *new* version of the provider.

To do this, it depends on the language you're using with Pulumi.

If you're using TypeScript or JavaScript, update your `@pulumi/digitalocean` dependency in your `package.json`

If you're using Python, update `pulumi_digitalocean` in your `requirements.txt`

Make sure you update with your package manager with `npm update` or `pip3 upgrade`

The same applies if you're using DotNet, Go and Java.

*then* you need to run a successful `pulumi up`. Pulumi will update the provider version associated with each resource as you saw above, you can verify this by again doing a `pulumi stack export`

From here, you should be able to successfully use your M1 mac without the legacy plugins.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. I had mistakenly assumed that `pulumi plugin` and the packages from my `requirements.txt` were referring to the same thing.